# React unit test: tried to test function's html tag but fail

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I got this error when I run unit test in react:

> TypeError: setArticleList.find is not a function
>
> 21 |         expect(setArticleList.find('div').length >0).to.equal(true);

**navList.test.js**

```
describe('NavList', function () {
    const app = shallow(<NavList/>);
    it('function setArticleList() ', function () {
        const setArticleList = app.instance().setArticleList();
        expect(setArticleList.find('div').length >0).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

**navList.js**

```
setArticleList(){
    return (
        <div className="list-unstyled d-flex align-items-center">
            <div>test</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Why **setArticleList.find is not a function**?
Something like following was passed:

**const app = shallow();**

**expect(app.find('h2').length).to.equal(1);**

Also if I modify **setArticleList()** like **setArticleList(){return true;}**

then run **expect(setArticleList).to.equal(true);**

Can be passed too.

So why did I got the error?

Comment: Anyone help plz?

Comment: .instance() only gets you the reference to the method in a component but won't render it. And you can use .find() only on shallow() or mount() references. You can not use find() on instance(). You should probably put your ArticleList code into a separate functional Component and test it separately or you should find this div on shallow rendered app variable in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you bind the function?
Try to bind the function on the main constructor

```
this.setArticleList = setArticleList.bind(this);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but it doesn't seems like the problem.